# Forward touch events to another view that is partially covered by the one that received the event

Tags: ios, events, uiview, gesture, touch-event

I have searched everywhere for a solution to this question but my case seems to be different.

I've got two views, specifically, one GMSMapView (map view from the google maps api) taking up the whole screen and another view on top of the map (not subview of it, but partially covering it). What  happens is that when I pinch with one finger starting on top of the second view and the other finger on top of the map, the map doesn't get the gesture. Since the second view has large transparent areas, I would also like that if I pan with one finger over those the map would get the gesture (move) but keeping buttons (subviews of the non-map view) tappable.

I have tried keeping a reference to the map view in the view class file of the non-map view and implement the hitTest method but the map still doesn't get any touches... Thanks a lot

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    // If the hitView is THIS view, return the map instead
    if (hitView == self)
    {
        return self.targetView; //the map view
    }
    // Else return the hitView (as it could be one of this view's buttons):
    return hitView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second view override pointInside method and return YES if that point is present on some tappable portions of your view (like buttons etc -check whether that point is inside buttons frame) otherwise retun NO.
So, if user taps on second view ,and if you return NO in pointInside, then pointInside of mapview will be called and so it will receive event. If you return YES, poinInside of mapView wont be called, so mapView wont receive event.
Hope this helps.